# Can I programatically make my website go to full screen via F11?

Tags: javascript

I want to make my page viewed at full screen.

How can I programatically press <kbd>F11</kbd> on page load. Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - not possible without JavaScript. And only then, you can open a large new window, but not emulate pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Also, changing browser window sizes without the user's consent is very frustrating for them.

Comment: k.using javascipt how can i press F11?

Comment: @Joby You can't. Read the answer.

Comment: Using this code its k...but using F11....window.open(theURL, ”, ‘fullscreen=no, toolbar=yes ,menubar=yes ,status=yes ,scrollbars=yes, location=yes, resizable=yes, maximized=0, height=800, width=1280, left=0,top=0′);

Comment: @Joby If you want to make a web application, you have to accept the trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* possible to open a window full screen on load. It is not possible to resize the page you are loading.

What you can do is to open a max size child window, say on click of a button etc (if you do it onload, popup blockers would block it).
If it is a corporate intranet then perhaps you can add a rule to all your browsers to add your site to the popup blicker whitelist.

You can also use flash (etc) to open a document full screen, but this is not probably what you are looking at.